# recall calculation for a real world example

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall

​I have totally `696,876` nodes in set *X*. I have `8,127,040` nodes in set *Y*. I am constructing an edge between set *X* and set *Y*. After constructing the edges between the 2 sets, I have `546,255` edges between set *X* and set *Y*.

Now, my algorithm has detected `3843` edges out of which `3450` are correct edges.

From [this](http://www.creighton.edu/fileadmin/user/HSL/docs/ref/Searching_-_Recall_Precision.pdf) link, I see that `recall` is the ratio of number of relevant records retrieved to the total number of relevant records in the database.

```
recall = A/(A+B) *10​0
```

Where,

> A = number of relevant records retrieved.
>   B = number of relevant records not retrieved.

So based on the above formula, I calculate my `recall` value as,

```
recall = 3450/546255 *100 = 0.631%
```

Is my `recall` calculation correct?